# javascript returning accurate date when time is 23:59:59.000

Tags: javascript

I'm returning a date from json and parsing it to a date format like so;

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
```

The problem is the date field in the database is set to 23:59:59.000 for the time.
The above code returns the day after using date.getDate().
I'm assuming this is due to the time.

How can i return the accurate date with the time being set to 23:59:59.000

Cheers

Edit
Incase anyone comes across this i fixed it by using;
var utc = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

Comment: What is an example of `date.substr(6)` that gives you a valid Date? Its too short for epoch which is the matching constructor ...

Comment: The epoch timestamp is 1533081599 which returns the day after as the local time.

Comment: But that's not 6 chars long (and is in seconds not millis)

Comment: Epoch timestamp is 1533081599000.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the database is storing the UNIX Epoch (in secs), try multiplying the parseInt with * 1000. This will also set the miliseconds to 0.

```
let timeFromDB = parseInt(date.substr(6)) * 1000
let date = new Date(timeFromDB);
```

[Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Integer value representing the number of **milliseconds** since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

The question was somewhat unclear, but hope this helps.

Comment: I have a date in the database as such '2018-07-12 23:59:59.000' When i return this date using var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6))); and then date.getDate() to display the date it always adds a day. This is because it is converting the epoch timestamp(1533081599000) into local time for me which is BST so its adding 1 hour to every date and returning 2018-07-13 00:59:59

Comment: Is the saved timestamp stored in UTC or in local time?